# How upload file to transfer.sh using cURL in Android

Tags: php, android, linux, curl, upload

In GNU/Linux we can upload our files to http://transfer.sh with cURL like this command in the terminal:

```
curl --upload-file MyFile.jpg http://transfer.sh
```

Now I wanna do it in my Android apps by using Java and Eclipse but I don't have any idea!
May someone help me about it?
How I can upload my device's files to this site?
Thank you guys.